# rename file from title - author to author - title

Tags: files, rename

my files are of the form War of the World - H. G. Wells.pdf
I would like
Wells H G - War of the Worlds.pdf
There are several other file extensions epub, mobi etc.
Is there a package that will do this - in bulk?
Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks

I should add that I have pyRenamer already.
Most files are of the format Title - Author.ext
eg Harry Potter blah de blah - J.K.Rowling.pdf
or
Some Other Title - Firstname Surname.epub

What I would like is
Surname Firstname - Title.ext
(os is Ubuntu 12.04LTS)
tia

Answer (score 4):

You can use the perl-based `rename` command: based on the 3 examples you have given so far, something like

```
rename 's/(.*)\s+[-]\s+(.*)\.(.{3,4})/$2 - $1.$3/' *.*
```

should work **however test it first by adding the `-n` and `-v` options** i.e.

```
$ touch "War of the World - H. G. Well.pdf"
$ touch "Harry Potter blah de blah - J.K.Rowling.pdf"
$ touch "Some Other Title - Firstname Surname.epub"
$ 
$ rename -nv 's/(.*)\s+[-]\s+(.*)\.(.{3,4})/$2 - $1.$3/' *.*
Harry Potter blah de blah - J.K.Rowling.pdf renamed as J.K.Rowling - Harry Potter blah de blah.pdf
Some Other Title - Firstname Surname.epub renamed as Firstname Surname - Some Other Title.epub
War of the World - H. G. Well.pdf renamed as H. G. Well - War of the World.pdf
```

See `man rename` for usage

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the easiest and readable way:

```
 mmv -v "* - *.pdf" "#2 - #1.pdf"
```

Here is a test:

```
$ ls
title - author.pdf  TITLE - AUTHOR.pdf  World - H. G. Wells.pdf
$ mmv -v "* - *.pdf" "#2 - #1.pdf"
TITLE - AUTHOR.pdf -> AUTHOR - TITLE.pdf : done
World - H. G. Wells.pdf -> H. G. Wells - World.pdf : done
title - author.pdf -> author - title.pdf : done
$ ls
author - title.pdf  AUTHOR - TITLE.pdf  H. G. Wells - World.pdf
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks very much.  Tom40

Answer (score -1):

Yes, [pyRenamer [image: Install pyRenamer]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pyrenamer/).

It is not very hard to figure out. I use it.

First select the folder where your files are located; they're usually located in the home user name or media then under insert/delete tab you can type what you want to add. There's a small icon option button up at the top right this will allow you to select all files and keep the file extension.

Then, hit preview after typing in what you want to add at the beginning if the check box is not checked and at end if it is.

If it looks good, hit rename, and you're done.

There are many more features. If you hover you mouse over stuff, a help box will appear.

Comment: Could you explain how to use it. I don't know :(

Comment: First select the folder where your files are located then